# How to access angular-component in ionic-page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have set up an ionic project and added a page "sumbuilder". After that, I added a component "partscount". The component was automatically added to the app.module.ts, but I didn't get managed to make the tag "`<app-partscount></app-partscount>`" running in my page. So I removed the component-declaration from app.module.ts, moved it to my sumbuilder.module.ts and then it worked.

Here is the working code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SumbuilderPage } from './sumbuilder.page';
import { PartcountsComponent} from '../partcounts/partcounts.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SumbuilderPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    SumbuilderPage, 
    PartcountsComponent
  ]
})
export class SumbuilderPageModule {}
```

Now the question: What do I have to add in this file (sumbuilder.module.ts) to access the Component, when it is declared in app.module.ts? I'm new to angular and sure, it is a beginner-question. Because I want to use this component more than once, I want to declare it in app.module.

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PartcountsComponent } from './partcounts/partcounts.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, PartcountsComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    PartcountsComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you mean that how we can declare a component in a module and use it in another module. If you mean so, here is the answer:

Each angular module must specify it's declared components using `declaration: []` of `@NgModule` decorator. If that module let other modules to use its components, then it must be specified in `exports: []` of `@NgModule`. In such situation, another module can import the module and use its exported components. Here is an example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'first-component',
  template: `<p> I'm first component </p>`
})
export class FirstComponent {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ FirstComponent ],
  exports: [ FirstComponent ]
})
export class MyFirstModule {}
```

In another module we can use exported `FirstComponent` of `MyFirstModule` :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ComponentWhichUsesFirstComponent ],
  imports: [ MyFirstModule ]
})
export class MySecondModule {}

@Component({
  selector: 'an-optional-selector',
  template: `<first-component>  </first-component>`
})
export class ComponentWhichUsesFirstComponent {}
```

See this [stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/exporting-declared-components) example.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think you are close to my solution. What if I declared the component in app.module.ts and now I want to access the component from my page. Do I have to Import "AppModule" in my sumbuilder.module.ts?

Comment: Yes, the import/export rule exists for any module.

Comment: I suggest to declare and export your component in sumbuilder.module.ts and import and use it in app.module.ts

Comment: Can you explain to me why? I thought you only need to declare a component once in appmodule and then you can access it from anywhere. This I wanted to do. When I declare the component in sumbuilder.module.ts I have no problems.

Comment: read this to get a deeper understanding of angular modules: https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407

Comment: Thank you! So I guess it would be helpful to build an extra module for my component if it is used more than once? If not, I can declare it in sumbuilder.module.ts. Right?